# How can find difference between value with out missing first sample?

Tags: r, difference

I like to find difference between my samples but when I use diff() my first sample miss.

input:

data

```
       XX.3.22  XX.1.2 XX.5.19 XX.2.21 XX.2.16 XX.5.27  XX.3.5 XX.2.12 XX.4.15 
       0.00      0.12    0.17     0.20    0.21    0.26    0.27   0.27     0.32
```

diff(data)

output:

```
 XX.1.2 XX.5.19 XX.2.21 XX.2.16 XX.5.27  XX.3.5 XX.2.12 XX.4.15 
   0.05    0.05   0.03    0.01    0.05     0.01   0.00   0.05
```

I do not want miss first (XX.3.22) sample.
I expect:
    XX.3.22 = 0.12

Comment: `diff` gives an output that has length 1 less than the length of the original vector.  You can concatenate 0 with the output ie. `c(0, diff(data))`

Comment: Thanks a lot.That command works good.